# Photo naming in QGIS.3.14 QFieldSync

Tags: qgis, qfield, photos, qfieldsync

In QGIS 3.14 / QfieldSync there is now the functionality to configure photo naming. Yay!

I use a 1:n set-up for photos, i.e. I capture photos in the child table ('photo') of a one-to-many relationship. I would like to name my photos based on attributes ('type' and 'num') in the parent layer ('tree').

So far, my attempt at the expression is as follows:

```
'DCIM/'||attributes(get_feature('tree','uuid','fkid'))['type'||'num']||'_'||now()||'.jpg'
```

This isn't working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

okay, with much playing around, this is now working:

```
case
when "fkid" is null then 
    'DCIM/'||
    format_date(Now(), 'yyyyMMdd_hhmmss')||
    '.jpg'
else
    'DCIM/'||
    attributes(get_feature('tree_pt','uuid',"fkid"))['type']||
    attributes(get_feature('tree_pt','uuid',"fkid"))['num']||'_'||
    format_date(Now(), 'yyyyMMdd_hhmmss')||
    '.jpg'
end
```

Notes:

- "fkid" is the foreign key in the photos layer.
- 'tree_pt' is the parent layer
- 'uuid' is the primary key in 'tree_pt'
- note the use of single and double quotes.

In my set-up, anyone of three parent layers may store image paths in 'photos'. So I wrap this up in coalesce() to check each layer for a match. Much like Highlander, there can be only one: I am using uuid.